# fetching names from one table with multiple ids in join

Tags: mysql, sql, join, subquery, inner-join

Employee

```
ID    Name   
1     John
2     Williams
```

Appointment

```
ID  DoctorName   Employee_id  Team lead
1    willson          1            2
```

SQL

```
SELECT E.*,A.* FROM Employee as E,Appointment as A WHERE A.Employee_id = E.ID
```

This is my join if i **want to fetch Team lead name**  how we can do that?

Comment: What is your expected answer?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
SELECT A.ID,A.DoctorName,E.Name as Employee,E1.Name as TeamLead
FROM Appointment A INNER JOIN
Employee E ON E.ID=A.Employee_id INNER JOIN
Employee E1 ON E1.ID=A.TeamLead
```

The result will be:

```
ID  DoctorName  Employee_id   TeamLead
---------------------------------------
1   willson     John          Williams
```

See result in [**SQL Fiddle**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/7420a8/2).

**EDIT:**

For including more tables, you need to join `Employee` table with different alias name:

```
SELECT A.ID,A.DoctorName,E.Name as Employee,E1.Name as TeamLead,E2.Name as AttendedBy, Att.Attended
FROM Appointment A INNER JOIN
tblAttended Att ON Att.Id=A.Id INNER JOIN
Employee E ON E.ID=A.Employee_id INNER JOIN
Employee E1 ON E1.ID=A.TeamLead INNER JOIN
Employee E2 ON E2.ID=Att.employee_id
```

Sample Result:

```
ID  DoctorName  Employee_id   TeamLead    AttendedBy     Attended
-----------------------------------------------------------------
1   willson     John          Williams    John           Y
```

Comment: Many Many Thanks for this. This works fine for me but i want to involve more table which is having Employee_id = logged in employee id

Comment: Which are the other tables?

Comment: tblAttended
ID  employee_id    Attended
1     1              Y

Comment: @user3042019: You should join Employee table in another alias to do that. I will edit my answer.

Comment: I need to show all the appointments One issue with this if some appointments are not attended its not showing.

Comment: @user3042019: Replace `INNER JOIN` with `LEFT OUTER JOIN`. Then you will get the desired result.

Comment: @user3042019: Feel free to accept the answer if you are satisfied. If you don't know how to accept the answer: there is a tick mark on the left side of my answer. If you want to mark this as accepted, then click on the tick mark.

Answer (score 0):

Try this one

```
SELECT E.name
FROM Employee E
JOIN Appointment A 
ON A.Employee_id = E.ID
WHERE [some condition here]
```

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
SELECT A.ID,A.DoctorName,E.Name,E1.Name 
FROM Employee E
INNER JOIN Appointment A
ON A.Employee_id = A.ID
WHERE E1.ID=A.Teamlead
```

Answer (score 0):

You have not used join. You need to use join here. Your TeamLead must be the same as Employee id. Based on that, you have to select the Employee name, and alias it as TeamLeadName.

```
SELECT A.ID, A.DoctorName, A.Employee_id, E.Name as TeamLeadName
FROM Appointment A
JOIN Employee E
ON A.TeamLead = E.ID
```

Answer (score 0):

IF Team Lead NAME IN Appointment TABLE THEN USE below QUERY:

```
SELECT E.Name AS 'Employee Name',A.DoctorName AS 'Doctor', A.TeamLeadName AS 'Team Lead' FROM Employee AS E,Appointment AS A WHERE A.Employee_id = E.ID;
```

IF Team lead NAME IN differnt TABLE LIKE TeamLead THEN USE below QUERY:

```
SELECT E.Name AS 'Employee Name',A.DoctorName AS 'Doctor', T.TeamLeadName AS 'Team Lead' FROM Employee AS E,Appointment AS A, TeamLead AS T WHERE A.Employee_id = E.ID AND A.TeamLead=T.TeamLead_ID;
```

If Williams is teamlead (which is not mention in your question) then use below query:

```
SELECT E.Name AS 'Employee Name',A.DoctorName AS 'Doctor', T.Name AS 'Team Lead' FROM Employee AS E,Appointment AS A, Employee AS T WHERE A.Employee_id = E.ID AND A.TeamLead=T.ID;
```