# How to join with three tables with multiple conditions?

Tags: join

I want to join three tables with multiple conditions. Below is table structure and expected result

```
users_id    users_first_name   
   1           rocky
   2           James
   3           john        

meeting_details_id   meeting_title   users_id  meeting_lead  close_meeting (NO) 
    1               newmeet          3           1                  No 
    2               testmeet         2           2                  No 


Attended_meetings
project_meeting_attendeeid  meeting_details_id  users_id   access_type (attendee) 
  1                             1                 2         attendee
```

Expected output:

Query should check if meeting is attended OR users is meeting lead

```
 meeting_title   creator   meeting_lead     close_meeting (NO) 
 newmeet          john      rocky                  No 
 testmeet         james     james                  No
```

Comment: *"Query should check if meeting is attended OR users is meeting lead"* - if the meeting always has a lead, it will always be included, regardless of whether or not it has been attended. From the available information, the `attended_meeting` table is irrelevant to the expected output.

Comment: mark then what it should be  if i want results as i.e  <br> for james i want to show two meetings newmeet and testmeet in one he is meeting lead and in one he has attended meeting

Comment: Posting specs and asking for code is not welcome to stackoverflow.

Comment: Possible duplicate of the [OP's prior question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22828603/fetching-names-from-one-table-with-multiple-ids-in-join).

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
SELECT M.meeting_title,U1.users_first_name as creator,U2.users_first_name as meeting_lead,M.close_meeting
FROM MeetingTable M LEFT OUTER JOIN
Users U1 ON M.creator=U1.users_id LEFT OUTER JOIN
Users U2 ON M.meeting_lead=U2.users_id
```

Result:

```
MEETING_TITLE   CREATOR     MEETING_LEAD    CLOSE_MEETING
newmeet         john        rocky           No
testmeet        James       James           No
```

See result in [**SQL Fiddle**](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/782aa/3).

Comment: little confusion about if logged in user is james ( 2) where should i put this condition i tried this but giving some different output

Comment: @user3042019: You mean meeting_lead?

Comment: for example james is logged in user his id is 2  he is lead in one meeting and he attended one meeting then how to use id 2 in this query Thanks for this help

Comment: @user3042019: Can you please elaborate? You want creator_id and meeting_lead_id to be shown?

Comment: for logged in user i want to show meetings in which he is meeting_lead and meeting which is attended by him  check third table please

Comment: @user3042019: My query will give you the expected result you mentioned in the question. Please edit the question and change the expected result to how you want it.

Comment: @user3042019: You mean client_detail_id in project_meeting_attendeeid ?

Comment: for record james i want to show two meetings newmeet and testmeet in one he is meeting lead and in one he has attended meeting